# Import specific class or function in Python Parallel job

Tags: python, pp-python-parallel

If you are using some modules in a function passed to **Server.submit** [[docs](http://www.parallelpython.com/content/view/15/30/)], you need to specify these in the *modules* argument. See below:

```
import os

def get_os_name():
  return os.name

jobserver.submit(get_os_name,modules=('os',))
```

But, I would like to do something like this:

```
from os import name

def get_os_name():
  return name

# Obviously won't work
jobserver.submit(get_os_name,modules=('os',))
```

How do I get the second code chunk to work? I tried replace 'os' with 'os.name' and stuff like that, but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
exec("jobserver.submit(get_os_name,modules=('os',))")
```